# Service api calling multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular

I am calling a service backend but it perform the call 2 or 3 times i don't know why, below i share my screen and code.

This is my service code.

```
public getClaimDataParam  (data:string) {
      let data1={
        "userid": this.userId,
        "status": data
      }
    return this.http.post(this.Api_urls[this.localStorage.get('app_mode')+''].newclaimUrl,data1).map((resp)=>{
    return resp;
        },(error)=>{
     this.spinner.hide()
     alert("Network Error")
   });
    }
```

This is my component.ts code

```
  getClaimList (data) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.spinnerService.show()
        this.batchService.getClaimDataParam(data).subscribe((resp)=>{

            this.spinnerService.hide()
            this.claimsData = resp;



            this.loading = false;

           this.tempClaimData = this.claimsData;
```

This my console screen shot(Please see **getallclaims** )

[image]

Comment: Don't you have multiple <my-components> initialization ?

Comment: API and UI code are running in same port or same domain ? if different it will hit two time. one with OPTION request another One with GET request

Comment: but it will hit more than 2 times